# Zopeskel ImportError: cannot import name BasicNamespace

Tags: plone, zope

I have zopeskel 2.21.2 in my virtualenv python and it works fine.  Meanwhile, I also have the same version of zopeskel in my Plone buildout (located in `~/.buildout/eggs`).  However, it does not work.  Running `zopeskel --list` throws the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name BasicNamespace
```

An advice from this [link](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting/exceptions.html#from-zopeskel-basic-namespace-import-basicnamespace) says to remove the egg.  I have removed the egg as well as the cached package in ~/.buildout/cache/dist/ and ran buildout again.  However, the problem persists.  The funny thing is that the paster script in the same buildout is working.

My zopeskel section in buildout.cfg looks like below:

```
[zopeskel]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
    ZopeSkel
    Paste
    PasteDeploy
    PasteScript
    zopeskel.dexterity
    ${instance:eggs}
```

Some package versions used in my buildout:

```
'/home/user/.buildout/eggs/Paste-1.7.5.1-py2.6.egg',
'/home/user/.buildout/eggs/distribute-0.6.24-py2.6.egg',
'/home/user/.buildout/eggs/PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.6.egg',
'/home/user/.buildout/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.4.2-py2.6.egg',
```

Full traceback:

```
[user@rizal myplone.site]$ ./bin/zopeskel --list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/zopeskel", line 346, in <module>
    import zopeskel.zopeskel_script
  File "/home/user/.buildout/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.6.egg/zopeskel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from zopeskel.basic_namespace import BasicNamespace
  File "/home/user/.buildout/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.6.egg/zopeskel/basic_namespace.py", line 2, in <module>
    from zopeskel.vars import var, DottedVar, StringVar, BooleanVar, TextVar
  File "/home/user/.buildout/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.6.egg/zopeskel/vars.py", line 2, in <module>
    from paste.script.templates import var as base_var
  File "/home/user/.buildout/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.4.2-py2.6.egg/paste/script/templates.py", line 6, in <module>
    import copydir
  File "/home/user/.buildout/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.4.2-py2.6.egg/paste/script/copydir.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/home/user/.buildout/eggs/distribute-0.6.24-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2727, in <module>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/home/user/.buildout/eggs/distribute-0.6.24-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 700, in subscribe
    callback(dist)
  File "/home/user/.buildout/eggs/distribute-0.6.24-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2727, in <lambda>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/home/user/.buildout/eggs/distribute-0.6.24-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2230, in activate
    map(declare_namespace, self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt'))
  File "/home/user/.buildout/eggs/distribute-0.6.24-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1827, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/home/user/.buildout/eggs/distribute-0.6.24-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1797, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName); module.__path__ = path
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pkgutil.py", line 238, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)
  File "/home/user/.buildout/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.6.egg/zopeskel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from zopeskel.basic_namespace import BasicNamespace
ImportError: cannot import name BasicNamespace
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: What versions of Paste, PasteDeploy and PasteScript are installed? You may also want to double-check the ZopeSkel egg version in the `bin/zopeskel` script. Last but not least, please include the *complete* traceback in your post; often there are clues hidden in that that help us help you.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the information you asked. In bin/zopeskel there is a line 'import zopeskel.zopeskel_script', does this mean that it uses the zopeskel version in my virtualenv python since I have zopeskel there as well?

Comment: No, the ZopeSkel egg pushed into your sys.path by the `bin/zopeskel` script will be searched for that first.

Comment: Its the correct one. In sys.path[0:0], one of the values is '/home/user/.buildout/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.6.egg'.

Comment: That does sound like the egg is corrupted; is there a `zopeskel/basic_namespace.py` file inside `'/home/user/.buildout/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.6.egg`?

Comment: I thought so too.  That's why I removed it and reinstalled again.  The package has a basic_namespace.py but it could not find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This usually happens you have ZopeSkel / Paster installed both locally (buildout) and in the global Python installation. Due to failures in Python process of managing site packages you end up with an incompatible combiation.

Solution:

http://docs.plone.org/manage/troubleshooting/exceptions.html#from-zopeskel-basic-namespace-import-basicnamespace

Comment: I found the link in my search and tried the fix.  However, it did not mention that it applies to my use case.  I deleted the version in my virtualenv and now zopeskel in my buildout works.  BTW, which is the better one to delete, the one in the virtualenv or in the buildout?

Comment: virtualenv. It is better to let the buildout to manage Plone related things. This is mostly managerial decision, technically it could be either.

Comment: I was leaning towards virtualenv also as it can be used for other projects.  I do not need to configure zopeskel in each of my buildout.  I just need to activate my virtualenv.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah: there is one reason why you *want* it in your buildout. Paster local commands (e.g. add contenttype) won't work in the templates unless Paster has access to your local eggs through PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Right. That escaped my mind.  Back to zopeskel in buildout then.

Comment: @Mikko: +1, had the same problem, your advice helped, thanks for documenting :)